# Video processing with opencv-reducing frame speed

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to detect emotion from a webcam video. However the frames are too fast to even do the classification. Any ideas on how I can slow or reduce the frames so I can be able to do my prediction?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the set up configuration? With just this few information, I'd suggest to replace the quartz of your webcam by a slower one ;).

Comment: get a camera that can capture more FPS

Comment: Change the algorithm working such a way that : 1 )Read the frame 2) Predict the emotion of that frame 3)Show the results 4 )Step 1 again. So Frames in between will aromatically skipped. The frame rate will depend upon the execution speed of your algorithm.

Comment: @RahulKP thank you...i am still a newbie in ML. Do you have an example of how i can capture frame by frame from this:  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)....ret, frame= cap.read()